# Deploy Laravel API and MySQL-Problems

Tags: mysql, laravel, api, deployment

First, I am a newbie in Laravel.

I have programmed an API that works fine local. Now I wanted to deploy this API to an existing Nginx server. I have set up some in my MySQL. And a "php artisan migrate" was successful. So everything works on the terminal. And I'm also on the direct url (currently on a VM) on the Laravel home page. But / home throws me the following error "Error establishing a database connection". I do not understand that. So the data in the. Env should be right, if I can create tables on the console. Basically, I do not need subpages. Actually, I just want to call my API. So GET, POST, PUT and DELETE. I thought that I do about 192.168.2.109/mtb/api/ROUTE. But that does not work that way either.

What am I doing wrong? I hope you feel sorry for a desperate beginner. I have been at the googlen since yesterday at noon (German time).

Best regards,

Helge

Comment: Have you set up multiple connections?

Comment: I have already thought about it and informed myself. But actually I just want to use my REST interface. Is not it enough if I adjust the .env of my MySQL and just load the whole project via WinSCP on the Ubuntu VM?

With project, I mean the whole Folder. With public, .env, app, routes. And all the other beautiful datas.

Comment: Is MySQL  on the same server as the website? If so, have you tried setting the DB_HOST in your .env file to '127.0.0.1', or 'localhost' ?

If you have ssh access to the server, log in and try running `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u <your_db_username> -p <your_db_name>` and entering the db password.  If you're logged into Mysql then the problem is either in your `.env` file or the `config/database.php` file.

Comment: There are two different databases. Wordpress and inventory. I have a new user for the inventory database. With this I can log in and have access to the data. In the env are the same data. That they are correct, I already see it, the artisan commands work. In fact, the database.php files (between server and local) were different. On the server, the data was hard on the code. I changed that again. Unfortunately, no new results. But many thanks for your help :).



if it should be interesting: https://github.com/TheSlowlySnail/MT_Backend_Iventorysystem

Comment: On the main site, is a WordPress Blog. Can that be a problem?